# The action of automorphisms on the Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, lie-groups, complex-geometry, group-actions

If we are given that the automorphism group of the Riemann sphere is $$Aut\ \mathbb P^1=\{z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}:ad-bc=1\}$$ Why this group does not have any proper subgroups that act without fixed points and properly discontinuously on $\mathbb P^1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function from the $2$-sphere to itself has no fixed points, then it is homotopic to the antipodal map. In particular it has degree $-1$.

Comment: Can you write more details please?

Comment: Which bit do you need more detail on?

Comment: How degree $-1$ implies the result?

Comment: A map $f\colon S^n \to S^n$ of degree $-1$ is orientation reversing (by definition). All analytic maps preserve orientation.

Comment: So we dont even need to know what the automorphism group is. Right?

Comment: I guess not. Sorry I'm not too familiar with geometry - mostly topology - so if this is a homework problem then perhaps you are being asked to prove this using methods available to you from geometry.

Comment: Actually,  I was thinking in proving that this automorphism group has no discrete subgroups .. if this was correct then we proved no properly discontinuous actions occur!

Answer (score 1):

Every conformal automorphism of the Riemann sphere has at least one fixed point, hence any descret subgroup of automorphism of the Riemann sphere is trivial.

Comment: Please consider using [mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in your posts.  Generally adding a new Answer to an older Question, even one with an Accepted Answer as here, is welcome provided some new information or approach is highlighted.  The brevity of your Answer leaves something to the Readers imagination regarding what that new information might be.  It would improve with either of those edits (math notation and/or highlighting what new information is given).